# Prove that $\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{\log (1+x)}{x}\right)^2dx$ converges.

Tags: calculus

Prove that $\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{\log (1+x)}{x}\right)^2dx$ converges.

I'm not sure where to begin here, perhaps show that it is bounded by something? This is an exercise I'm doing to review calculus.

Comment: Since WolframAlpha evaluates this, it might be interesting to ask: Prove the integral above is equal to $\pi^2 /3$.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman that is elementary.

Comment: @Chris'ssis I only comment that it is *interesting*; I fail to see how responding about its being "elementary" is relevant. If you mean elementary as in easy, then I note that it is more difficult than the original problem (which asks only for convergence, and doesn't ask to what it converges). If you mean elementary as in doesn't require complex analysis, then I refer you back to the first sentence of this comment.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman it was just an opinion, nothing more. I agree it's interesting too.

Comment: @Chris'ssis If it is elementary, could you provide a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is potential trouble near $0$, and also for large $x$. It is useful to break up the integral into the integral from $0$ to (say) $1$, and from $1$ to $\infty$. If each integral converges, our integral does.

**From $0$ to $1$:** We look at the behaviour of $\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\right)^2$ for positive $x$ near $x=0$.

By L'Hospital's Rule, we have $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$. So, appearances to the contrary, our function is very well behaved near $x=0$. If we define it to be $0$ at $x=0$, it is continuous. Thus the integral from $0$ to $1$ converges.

**From $1$ to $\infty$:** Rewrite our function as $\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^{1/2}}$.

By using L'Hospital's Rule, we can show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^{1/2}} =0$.

Thus for large enough $x$, $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^{1/2}}\le 1$. It follows that for large enough $x$, our function is $\lt \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$. By Comparison, the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

The convergence has been established by @André Nicolas.

By integrating by parts, one may observe there is a closed form of the given integral, 
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x} \right)^2dx&=\left.- \frac1x \cdot \ln^2(1+x) \right]_0^\infty+2\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}\:dx
\\&=\color{red}{0}+2 \cdot \frac {\pi^2}6
\\&=\color{blue}{\frac {\pi^2}3}
\end{align}
$$ where we have used
$$
2\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}\:dx=4\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+t^2)}{t(1+t^2)}\:dt=4\cdot \frac {\pi^2}{12}=\color{blue}{\frac {\pi^2}3}
$$ proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612774/how-to-evaluate-the-following-integrals-involving-frac-log1x2x1x2/2612799#2612799).