# Evaluate $\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(1+x^3\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\:dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How to acomplish the evaluation of $$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(1+x^3\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\:dx$$
I got the integral to be
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(1+x^3\right)}{x}\:dx-\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(1+x^3\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
But im stuck, can someone give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: It's not valid to split the integral up like this in this case, since ${\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x}dx}$ diverges. We can only split it up like this **if both individual integrals converge**, which is not true in this case. I don't think any solution method will be particularly "elementary" (depending on what you define as elementary) in this problem

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $x = \tan \theta$?

Comment: The integral in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612774/how-to-evaluate-the-following-integrals-involving-frac-log1x2x1x2) looks very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note

$$ \int _1^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(1+x^3\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\:dx
\overset{x\to\frac1x} = \int _0^{1}\frac{x\ln \left(1+x^3\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx
- \int _0^{1}\frac{3x\ln x}{1+x^2}\:dx
$$

Then

\begin{align}
\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(1+x^3\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\:dx
& = \int _0^{1}\frac{\ln \left(1+x^3\right)}{x}\:dx
 - \int _0^{1}\frac{3x\ln x}{1+x^2}\:dx \\
& = \int _0^{1}\frac{\ln \left(1+x^3\right)}{x}\:dx
 +\frac32 \int _0^{1}\frac{\ln (1+x^2)}{x}\:dx \\
 & = \frac13 \int _0^{1}\frac{\ln \left(1+t\right)}{t}\:dt
 +\frac34\int _0^{1}\frac{\ln (1+t)}{t}\:dt \\
 & = \frac{13}{12} \int _0^{1}\frac{\ln (1+t)}{t}\:dt \\
&=  \frac{13}{12}\cdot \frac{\pi^2}{12}= \frac{13\pi^2}{144}
\end{align}

[$\int _0^{1}\frac{\ln (1+t)}{t}\:dt=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046219/find-int1-0-frac-ln1xxdx)

Comment: It works nice using Feynman's trick. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Using Feynman's trick.*

$$I(a)=\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\log \left(1+a^3x^3\right)}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}\:dx$$
$$I'(a)=\int _0^{\infty }\frac{3a^2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right) \left(1+a x^3\right)}\,dx$$ Use partial fraction decomposition, the integrand write
$$\frac{a^2}{\left(a^2+1\right) (a x+1)}-\frac{3 \left(a^5
   x+a^2\right)}{\left(a^2+1\right) \left(a^4-a^2+1\right)
   \left(x^2+1\right)}+\frac{(2 a^5-a^3) x-a^4+2 a^2}{\left(a^4-a^2+1\right)
   \left(a^2 x^2-a x+1\right)}$$ Computing $I'(a)$ is quite simple and the final result is
$$I'(a)=\frac{2 \pi  a}{\sqrt{3} \left(a^6+1\right)}+\frac{3 a^5 \log (a)}{a^6+1}+\frac{2
   \pi  a^3}{\sqrt{3} \left(a^6+1\right)}-\frac{3 \pi  a^2}{2 \left(a^6+1\right)}$$

For sure, the integration with repect to $a$ is not the most pleasant but everything simplifies at the bounds
$$J=\int_0^1 I'(a)\,da=\Big[\frac{1}{144} \left(36
   \left(\text{Li}_2\left((-1)^{1/3}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-(-1)^{2/3}\right)
   \right)-53 \pi ^2\right) \Big] -\Big[-\frac{4 \pi ^2}{9} \Big]$$
$$J=-\frac{17 \pi ^2}{48}+\frac{4 \pi ^2}{9}=\frac{13 \pi ^2}{144}$$